# Update Office manifest private host

Tags: office365, office-js

How can I update Office (Word) manifest after deploying, when the manifest is deployed via [Office 365 admin center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f) and the add-in is hosted on private Azure - so **not** the public Microsoft Store.

The new manifest is uploaded in Office 365 admin center, but users still see the previous add-in/manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated manifest will not be pulled unless there is a change in your version number. If the version remains the same it will use the cached version until that cache expires. Once the version changes it will force the cached manifest to be purged from the local machine.

Comment: Our customer gets an error when he uploads the manifest that contains a new version number: The app does not support any office products.
Is this a known problem in Office 365 admin center?
(this feature is only available in USA, not in Europe)

Comment: There have been some reports of issues using Chrome to deploy manifests but I've not been able to replicate it. They may want to try using Edge or Firefox and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, using Internet Explorer also results in: "the app does not support any office products".

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the validation code we currently have in production. We are working to get that updated to unblock this

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Problem is solved. The manifest can be deployed by Office 365 Admin Center.